# Is it possible to integrate a link back to my app on Instagram stories like how Spotify, Pandora did with their play button?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to allow users to post a song that they like on our app to their instagram stories and then have their followers be able to play that song by clicking onto a button which would then take the followers back to our app.  Similar to the Spotify play button or Pandora or Netflix button on Instagram stories.

Is this possible or is this something that Instagram only allows with these big companies?

Comment: Try to Google Deeplinking, and read about it.